# Do I need to wrap strings with '' when using Doctrine update set method?

Tags: doctrine

I am using Doctrine Update query as follow.

$oQuery = Doctrine_Query::create()
          ->update("Model")
          ->set("field",$value);

the problem is that if $value is string, I have to ->set("field","'".$value."'");

if it normal? Why can't doctrine do it itself?

am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use proper Doctrine syntax:

```
...
->update('Model m')
->set('m.field', '?', $value)
...
```

This old document will tell you all about it:

http://www.symfony-project.org/doctrine/1_2/en/06-Working-With-Data